# Direct2D "Attempt to access invalid address error" on EndDraw

Tags: c++, direct2d

Users of our application experience intermittent bug where ID2D1RenderTarget::EndDraw returns an HRRESULT 0x800701E7 which means "Attempt to access invalid address error". Using EndDraw tags we did pinned down the drawing operation that is causing the error using which is simple:

```
context->DrawImage(bitmap, offsetPoint, imageRectangle);
```

The problem is that we are not able to reproduce the error even if we are really trying by deleting the bitmap after drawing operation. It looks like Direct2D maintains it's own copy for drawing. Does anybody experience the same error and know how to cause it?

Comment: Should the bitmap even exist when this call happens? Not enough info to really help, but I would if check them, and if you're tesing and actively want it to crash to get more info then assert `context` and `btimap`.

Comment: @George: If `context` is a `nullptr`, you wouldn't get a COM `HRESULT` error. You'd trigger an SEH exception instead.